# Jasmine spyOn with Observables - using arrow functions vs passing the function to an RxJs operator

Tags: javascript, jasmine, rxjs

I have a function, actually a method in a Typescript class called HouseService, that looks like this

```
myHouse() {
    return this.bricks$
    .pipe(
      map(bricks => this.buildHouse(bricks)),
    );
}
```

this method listen to an Observable, `this.brick$`, and as soon as some *bricks* are notified builds a house using the method `this.buildHouse(bricks: Array).

Then I write a test that checks that `this.buildHouse` method is only called once. The test looks like this and works perfectly

```
  it('"buildHouse()" method is called only once for one event of "bricks$"', () => {
    spyOn(houseService, 'buildHouse').and.callThrough();
    houseService.bricks$.next(newBricks);
    expect(houseService.buildHouse).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

So far everything works fine.

Now the problem. I change the implementation of the myHouse method, getting rid of the fat arrow function and substituting it with the pure method reference, as follows

```
myHouse() {
        return this.bricks$
        .pipe(
          map(this.buildHouse),
        );
}
```

The runtime continues to work perfectly, but the test does not work anymore since it reports that `buildHouse` has been called 0 times. Can anybody explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `myHouse` function is executed before you mock that function. Therefore the original (not mocked) function is passed to `map`.

With arrow function it's executed each time the map calls it's callback - at that time the `buildHouse` is already mocked.